# Auto-detect a string in received email via POP3?

Tags: php, download, pop3

I was just wondering some hidden potential in a device I own, and after thinking a while, came up with this:

If an email is sent to "name@domain.com" (this would be specific to the device) from a specific sender, with a part of the body of the message containing a link, can I make a PHP script that accesses said account via POP3, detect emails sent to the address via a specific sender, and then download the file (link) in the email with string "http://www.domain.com/redirect.html?_encoding=" to a directory on my server?

Basically this:

specified sender emails "name@domain.com" with an email that contains a link specified above. PHP script (being called by a web browser) uses POP3 to download the link in the email from the specified sender, saves it to "C:\directory\filename.suffix" automatically?

Even better, is it possible without a PHP script, something that would automatically download the link when the email is received and save it to a directory on the local computer?

Thanks, I'm just trying to find if it is even possible and not waste my time.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Send an e-mail, and automate a download on a client?  You should create an application that runs on the client then.

Comment: I've got a server running, and I need it to check via POP3 every 5 minutes or so for new emails. If an email is from "sender@notify.com" it will automatically have a link with the string I provided above. Can I make it scan for the link and download it as a file (it's going to be a .pdf file but the name changes) and save it to a directory on the local machine?

Comment: You've got a server running **what**?  Can you make **what** scan for a link?  What runs on the local machine?  Be clear.

Comment: @Brad: Server running doesn't matter. It's windows server 2k3. Make "the script" scan for a link.

Comment: I meant, the server runs your script?  POP3 server?  Both?  Of course the OS doesn't matter.  Yes, it is entirely possible to read a POP3 box with PHP.  You didn't answer my 3rd question... You should really write better questions.

Comment: The server will host the script on its webserver-ness. It will access it with 127.0.0.1/script.php and it will move the downloads to a folder on its own self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [flourish fMailbox](http://flourishlib.com/docs/fMailbox). You can easily access your emails via POP3 with that and check them for your criteria.

One disadvantage if you run the script regularly (e.g. with a cronjob): It's based on the email's 'uid', which probably means 'unique id' - but (at least in my case) it's not so unique at all and changes if you delete emails from the server. So in other words, it's not a unique id but describes the nth email, counting from the first one. So if you don't want to start from the beginning each time you check your mails, you a.) have to store your last 'uid' somewhere and start from there and b.) should not delete emails from the server.

For the rest of your question:

Look if there's a specific link in there: http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Download the contents: http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: Thanks. I think I'll be able to make a scheduled event that executes the PHP script by itself, which would effectively solve the question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. Click this link and scroll-down all the way to the bottom where a user left a comment regarding accessing POP3 folders:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php